# Using webforms in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms

I am learning MVC, following [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in-7#Lab%204%3a-%20Creating%20simple%20MVC%20data%20entry%20screen) tutorial. (link will take you directly to where i'm stuck). so far I have learnt, there's a controller for every view. Now i have to take input from user through web entry form as mentioned in tutorial. In my project, i have a controller named **Default1** and i can run it as localhost:xyz/Default1/Index. it runs perfect.

Then i created a new Controller, named **Default2** and bound it to some view to display some data, and it worked perfect as localhost:xyz/Default2/Displaycustomer. the customer information was static (hard coded). and controller is as:

```
    public ViewResult DisplayCustomers()
    {
        Customer cobj = new Customer();
        cobj.Code = "12";
        cobj.Name = "Zeeshan";
        cobj.Amount = 7000;


        return View("DisplayCustomers",cobj);
    }
```

Now i have to take input from User, regarding cutomer iformation, using **html page** as mentioned in tutorial. so i tried adding a new **webform** under **view** folder, and and modified my controller as:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ViewResult DisplayCustomers()
    {
        Customer cobj = new Customer();

        cobj.Code = Request.Form["Id"].ToString();
        cobj.Name = Request.Form["Name"].ToString();
        cobj.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["Amount"].ToString());

        return View("DisplayCustomers",cobj);
    }
```

**My Question is**: How can i make my project stared, so that it takes input first, and then displays it, using above controller? Did i add the webform at right location? What would be the link to run it? i tried localhost:xyz/Default2/entryform etc. but failed.
(in my entryform.aspx, i have mentioned form **action="DisplayCustomer"** )

Comment: how is your view look like? when you say modify your controller, is that mean in the controller you only have one HttpPost method?? or you also have one HttpGet as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're missing is an action to just display the form. In otherwords, you just need an action to display a form.  That form's POST action should reference your controller's `DisplayCustomers` action.

So in your controller code:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult New()
    {
       return View("NewCustomer");  //Our view that contains the new customer form.
    }

    // Add your code for displaying customers below
}
```

And in your view, you have code like this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("DisplayCustomers", "Customer")) {
    <!-- Add your form controls here -->
}
```

Notice that I'm using the version of the BeginForm helper that specifies the action method and controller to call. This will write the `form` tag to post back to your `DisplayCustomers` action.  Here is the equivalent HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/Customer/DisplayCustomers">
```

You would then access your form using the URL http://test.server/Customer/New.

Comment: Thanks. I want to know 2 things. **1:** from your answer, i assume that I have created a controller named, **Customer** that is for our entry form view, named, **NewCustomers**. And in our entry form, we have specified that it will call another controller, named **DisplayCustomers**, which will display customer view. Did i get it right? **2:** Let's suppose, i'm not using this html helper thing, then i'll have to specify the <form action="Displaycustomerpage"> .. right?

Comment: @Zeeshan Your first assumption is half right. Yes, we created a new controller called **Customer**, but both **New** and **DisplayCustomers** are a part of that one controller.  As for your second question, if you don't use the helper the method will be POST and the action will be http://test.server/Customer/DisplayCustomers.  I'll update my answer with that detail.

Comment: Fine. I've started getting the chemistry :) you mean, in the same controller, we have 2 methods, for 2 views. right?

Comment: You got it! Controllers are meant to house the behavior of the object, entity, or area of concern that they're named after.

Comment: Thanks ALOT :) and why do i use **[HttpPost]** for DisplayCustomers() ?

Comment: and why should it be **ViewResult** and not **ActionResult** ?

Comment: oops! I guess, i should study these things by myself :P thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best example in the world...but this will at least get you rolling..

url would be:localhost:1234/Home/Customer

the controller

```
public ActionResult Customer()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Customer(FormCollection frm)
    {

        var name = frm["name"].ToString();
        var address = frm["address"].ToString();

        ViewBag.Name = name;
        ViewBag.Address = address;

        return View();
    }
```

The view

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address"/>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

         <input type="text" name="namedisplay" value='@ViewBag.Name'/>
        <input type="text" name="addressdisplay"  value='@ViewBag.Address'/>

    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. can you please explain, where should i keep the view, and what its name, and where my app has specified to call the view first? Sorry, I'm newbie.